# Magento module with product attribute and Custom Source Model - Uninstal

Tags: magento

When creating a module in Magento which adds a new product or category attribute that requires a custom source model, it appears that if the module is deactivated or removed then the product and category pages will not load correct.  This makes sense as it trying to load an attribute from a class that is no longer there.

How can this be dealt with without making the end user remove the attribute form the database manually

Comment: There is no uninstall functionality in magento. You should provide custom uninstall script to your customers.